# Share a variable to be used by two function without making it global

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-3.0

I am in a situation where a variable needs to be shared by two function. One way is to make it global. But by making it global, other functions will also have access to that variable. I want that particular variable to be accessed by selected functions only. Is there any way to achieve this type of functionality either by making it global with restriction or bay any other way?

Comment: The classic way is to have the two functions in one class with the class having a private instance field. You don't want to do that?

Comment: are the two methods called from the same object? can you imagine to pass this variable in the parameter list?

Comment: @flq..My all variable are of type private and all functions are in the class so this is not possible..

Comment: @Davide Piras..Yes same object calls both the function..

Comment: @Chirag, I still don't understand... if the "all" variable is in the class the functions can naturally access it..?

Comment: @flq.Yes but it was my mistake..Actually I am taking about methods and not functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the "classic" way you could operate with closures:

```
public class ClosureProvider {
  private Foo shared;

  public Func<object> GetFirst() {
    return new Func<object>(() => { /* Use shared and whatever else */ });
  }

  public Action<Bar> GetSecond() {
    return new Action<Bar>(bar => { /* Use shared and whatever else */ });
  }
}
```

The c# compiler will build the required infrastructure for you and the two returned functions have access to shared and whatever other things you want to use

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it between the functions as a parameter.